# OpenAPI generator spring: custom parameters for endpoint controller method, Join annotations for models

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, openapi, openapi-generator

First thing first, I am relatively new to java and spring ecosystem.

That out of the way, I am using OpenAPI to describe my REST API. The application uses spring boot 3 and security 6. I want to autogenerate as much code as possible. An example endpoint specification:

```yaml
/cashcards:
  post:
      summary: Create a new cash card.
      tags:
        - demo
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Created
          headers:
            Location:
              schema:
                type: string
              description: Created cashcard location.
      operationId: postCashCard
      description: Create a new cash card.
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/CashCardDetail'
            examples:
              Example 1:
                value:
                  amount: '100.10'
                  owner: sarah
        description: A cash card without ID
      security:
        - OAuth2-Authorization:
            - 'write:cashcards'
```

Right now I am using the [OpenAPI generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to generate API and model classes. Then overriding the API method for a specific endpoint in a controller class and writing the logic there.

I am facing some hurdles. As I am using spring boot and spring security, I want some of my controller methods to have parameters like

```java
default ResponseEntity<Void> postCashCard(
        @Parameter(name = "CashCardDetail", description = "A cash card without ID") @Valid @RequestBody(required = false) CashCardDetail cashCardDetail
    )
```

But I want the controllers to be like

```java
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_write:cashcards')")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> postCashCard(@RequestBody CashCard newCashCardRequest, UriComponentsBuilder ubc,
            Principal principal)
```

Ofcourse, as the method parameters are not same, I can not override the auto generated API method. Adding the `UriComponentsBuilder` and `Principal` in the API parameter does not make sense.

Similarly, I will use spring data jpa. using Annotations like `@OneToMany`, `@JoinColumn` seems difficult as well.

If anyone using the openapi generator in actual production use cases, I want to know how these problems are solved. How method parameters which is not related to OpenAPI definition is auto generated? How model field annotations etc are added to the autogenerated code?

If the auto generator goal is entirely different than what I am trying to achieve, I want to hear that. Right now I have to add the `@PostAuthrize` manually even if the scopes/security scheme is defined in OpenAPI. Writing codes manually without using generators seems faster.

Thank you for you kind patience.

Answer (score 0):

You don't modify the parameters of the controller methods. In this case those extra parameters can be read in the code within the method (or surrounding class) as follows:

Class level field

```
UriComponentsBuilder ubc = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
      .scheme("https").host("www.altron.com").path("/users");
```

Within controller method

```
Principal principal = (Principal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Comment: Will field injection using @Autowired work ok for UriComponentsBuilder  and Principal?

Comment: ‘@Autowired will work for UriComponentsBuilder but not for Pincipal because it is linked to each incoming request.